# File.WriteAllText Doesn't Preserve Newline

Tags: c#, .net

The Output of this code

```
string fileDateTime = "StepsGA-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss") + ".txt";
string fname = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, fileDateTime);
File.WriteAllText(fname, txtSteps.Text);
```

doesn't preserve newline as it should be. All the contents of the textbox are printed in a horizontal long line ! Where have I gone wrong? Thanks !

Comment: Check `txtSteps.Text` in the debugger to see whether it even contains newlines...

Comment: Can you check if txtSteps.Text has newlines in it ? I tried a sample code which had new lines in it and it worked for me.

Comment: This is the txtSteps output does contain newlines !
However it all appears in a straight line !. Any other method to achieve the same result?

Comment: Can you post the string value of txtSteps.Text ? Do you have "\n" as your new line or just "\r" ?

Comment: @ryadavilli Yeah sure. I am using \n every time. http://i.imgur.com/hIIaQ.png.

Comment: The windows linebreak is "\r\n"

Comment: Both TextBox and RichEditBox are forgiving, accepting both \n and \r\n as line endings.  Your text editor probably is not.  Avoid accidents by using File.WriteAllLines() instead, passing the textbox' Lines property.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Got the answer ! Instead of `\n` I needed to use `Environment.NewLine`.