# No line breaks when using File.WriteAllText(string,string)

Tags: c#, file, line-breaks

I noticed that there are no line breaks in the file I'm creating using the code below. In the database, where I also store the text, those are present.

```
string story = "Critical error occurred after " 
  + elapsed.ToString("hh:mm:ss") 
  + "\n\n" + exception.Message;
File.WriteAllText(path, story);
```

So after some [short googling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14119047/1525840) I learned that I'm supposed to refer to the new lines using *Environment-NewLine* rather than the literal *\n*. So I added that as shown below.

```
string story = "Critical error occurred after " 
  + elapsed.ToString("hh:mm:ss") 
  + "\n\n" + exception.Message;
  .Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
File.WriteAllText(path, story);
```

Still, no line breaks in the output file. What Am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try StringBuilder methods - it's more readable and you don't need to remember about `Environment.NewLine` or `\n\r` or `\n`:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

string story = sb.Append("Critical error occurred after ")
               .Append(elapsed.ToString("hh:mm:ss"))
               .AppendLine()
               .AppendLine()
               .Append(exception.Message)
               .ToString();
File.WriteAllText(path, story);
```

Simple solution:

```
string story = "Critical error occurred after " 
  + elapsed.ToString("hh:mm:ss") 
  + Environment.NewLine + exception.Message;
File.WriteAllLines(path, story.Split('\n'));
```

Comment: Didn't resolve the original issue, although the suggestion itself is good. I posted a very simple example, skipping the builder, to keep things shorter. The point is to use *File* class instead of any of the others used for writing and still get the line breaks. Is that possible at all?

Comment: @KonradViltersten updated answer, just replace `\n` with `Environment.NewLine` and it works

Comment: Hehe, did you see the second example of mine? The extra line, second from the end? I'm adding the *Environment.NewLine* but it **still** doesn't get into the file. Hence the question. But I'll throw you a freebie because I've found what's wrong. Instead of *WriteAllText*, I need to go *WriteAllLines* and *Split* the story.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using

```
File.WriteAllText(path, content);
```

use

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, content.Split('\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  WriteLine() method like below code

```
   using (StreamWriter sw = StreamWriter(path)) 
        {
            string story = "Critical error occurred after "  +elapsed.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
            sw.WriteLine(story);   
            sw.WriteLine(exception.Message); 
        }
```

Comment: There's no such method in *File*. I can change to another class, of course, but I wish to keep it short. And I'm curious about getting no line breaks in *File* class...

Answer (score -2):

WriteAllText strips newlines, because it is not text.

Comment: This is factually incorrect. Have you tried it? It accepts all characters in the given encoding. This includes the two characters you need for a newline in Windows.