# Outputting carriage return from variable set in XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I know it's been asked numerous times and while my question might seem to be a duplicate, I can't make the list of solutions work.
How come that doesn't seem to add "\r\n" or CRLF in my output file ?

```
<xsl:variable name="Newline">&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:variable>
...
<xsl:text>UpperLine</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$Newline"/>
<xsl:text>LowerLine</xsl:text>
```

Even when looking a tthe hexadcimal representation of the file, I can't see the 0d0a equivalent of CRLF (I can only see the ones at the end)

[image]

I've also tried this with no success either :

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('New Line', '&#13;&#10;')"/>
```

Comment: Please provide a *complete* stylesheet.

Comment: After more investigation, my problem is more specific than I originally stated. Let me try to explain :
I get the result of my XSLT into a C# code. This C# Code writes the XSLT content result into a CSV file (using File.WriteAllText()). It seems that the result of &#xD;&#xA; in the C# string is \n. shouldn't it be \r\n ?
The solution i found is to do what was proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118626/file-writealltext-doesnt-preserve-newline)

Answer (score 6):

change your variable declaration to this:

`<xsl:variable name="Newline"><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>`

Comment: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: Because XSLT strips whitespace text nodes from the stylesheet unless their parent is xsl:text. (And of course XSLT decides whether something is whitespace based on the output of the XML parser, not the input to the XML parser, so using character entities makes no difference.)